# All-caps trademark usage. Do I have to follow the all-caps recommendation?

Tags: capitalization, trademarks

There is a trademark product that is registered with all-caps (example: [**MATLAB<sup>®</sup>**](https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab.html)). However, the all-caps formatting is usually considered bad practice, so the spelling with only title-caps (**Matlab**) has been used very widely.

The brand-book from the trademark owner insists on the usage of the all-caps term ([MATLAB product usage in brand-book from MathWorks)](https://www.mathworks.com/brand/editorial/referring-to-products.html#matlab); however, the brand-book is directed for [the people associated with the trademark owner](https://www.mathworks.com/brand.html):

> Audience for This Guide
>
> The brand guide is for MathWorks distributors, external creative contractors, and agencies who create MathWorks materials.

and not necessarily other users.

My questions (assuming this question has nothing to do with legal documents, where such stuff might matter):

- Do I violate any common spelling practices by using a better-looking and easier typable title-caps spelling (e.g., Matlab) as opposed to the trademarked spelling?
- Would the answer change if we are talking about publishing in a reputable journal? (assuming the style guide of the journal omits this issue)
- Is there general consensus about all-caps trademarks being a bad practice?

Comment: I suggest you look up the meaning of "nonchalant"!

Comment: Potential legal issues aside (I'm not sure if this has ever been a real issue), It depends on the style guide that you follow. Some will say to keep it in all caps, others will say to use title caps regardless.

Comment: @MarkBeadles I wanted to use the fancy non-existing word "chalant" (that's why I italicized it); however, my auto spell-checker silently disagreed with me. Anyway, I reverted to the more formal language.

Comment: @SvenYargs that actually helps a lot! Your reference to the copyright law practices makes a lot of sense and gives a nice judgment point in a relatively grey area. I flagged this question to be closed as a duplicate, mostly because it contains a reference to Matlab, and in computational science community there is some fuss about its spelling.